# 404 Not found error even though Function App is deployed

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have created a function App in .net core 2.0 to e hosted on azure functions. I used FTP to upload the files, and FTP tool shows that files are uploaded under wwwroot folder. 
But still I see the message 404 resource not found when I hit this from my testbed

POST is enabled on api.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: my hosting o/s is windows

Comment: It seems like you have deleted your app so I cannot locate your Function App and check for any on-going errors on our end. Could you try restarted the Function App? Also, kindly verify that all the files are uploaded on Azure side. You can do this by going to the Kudu console (see https://david-obrien.net/2016/07/azure-functions-kudu/).